# 5032 Error code does not exist on the sorbet error reference

Tags: sorbet

https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/c6e86f50872a60adfba7b7472055dcc6c25e492c/core/errors/resolver.h#L38

This error reference - 5032 for IncludesNonModule does not exist on the website

Answer (score 0):

The [error reference](https://sorbet.org/docs/error-reference) page is open source like the rest of Sorbet, and the source is [editable directly in GitHub](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/edit/master/website/docs/error-reference.md)

This looks more like a request directly for Sorbet than a SO question, though.